# Dependent drop down + fixed formulas&calculations

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

What I have here is one sheet with some manual typed calculations. On the first upper table (Named as XYZ) you got an overview which is fixed, some specs of the system where Row 6 is type of the system what is actually important for the next step.

On the second table, starting from B16 (drop down field) are the values that are combining 1st Table (XYZ) and 3rd Table (ABC) using manually defined formulas as you can see in rows 21 and 22:

```
ROW 21 (3,14*($C$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000)  Volume (L)
```

and

```
ROW 22 $C$11-C21  Remaining Volume (L)
```

The thing is, this is only for one type of the system (CC025), and whole table should be populated for all the systems (from XYZ upper table) once when chosen on drop downs in Row B16. What I used is nested IF function:

```
=IF($B$16="CC025";(3,14*($C$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);IF($B$16="CC070";(3,14*($D$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);IF($B$16="CC100";(3,14*($E$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);IF($B$16="CC200";(3,14*($F$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);IF($B$16="CSM015";(3,14*($G$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);IF($B$16="CSM025";(3,14*($H$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);IF($B$16="CSM065";(3,14*($I$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);IF($B$16="CSM125";(3,14*($J$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);IF($B$16="CSM195";(3,14*($K$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000))))))))))
```

OR just newer version =IF**S**

```
=IFS(B16="CC025";(3,14*($C$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);B16="CC070";(3,14*($C$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);B16="CC100";(3,14*($C$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);B16="CC200";(3,14*($C$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);B16="CSM015";(3,14*($C$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);B16="CSM025";(3,14*($C$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);B16="CSM065";(3,14*($C$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);B16="CSM125";(3,14*($C$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000);B16="CSM195";(3,14*($C$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000))
```

But generally speaking it is fine, it works but is there any other way to make this calculation shorter?
This fall on my mind at first place, but I have to show this to some colleagues which are not so good in excel, and once shown like this would be "WTF" it looks complicated - even it is not =)  Any ideas how I can write and get same results on another maybe shorter way??

Thx
[image]

Comment: I just want to say that I like the layout and color you choose. It's quite pleasant :))

Comment: @TheGridLock haha.. well, I can send you color codes - RGBs :D

Comment: You have given 2 formulas but they are different, you can present it more briefly, how to optimize the formula instead of too long to follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula is probably what you need:

- you don't need to repeat the const in the formula such as `3.14` and `4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000`
- since the result is a number so I will use sumproduct instead of if, just multiply the arrays together

.

```
 =3.14*SUMPRODUCT((B16={"CC025","CC070","CC100","CC200","CSM015","CSM025","CSM065","CSM125","CSM195"})*$C$8:K8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000
```

[image]

Comment: Thx,,that was good idea but one small thing in your formula: this part where you included whole row range  *$C$8:K8^2     doesnt work properly, actually when I take "K8" then it is working,    But drop downs are not functioning too when I change?

Comment: `whole row range *$C$8:K8^2 doesnt work properly, actually when I take "K8" then it is working` can you explain more?

Comment: Interesing is, for ssecond formula works perfectly actually, for the fornula "Remaining Volume", I adjusted it like this: =SUMPRODUCT(($B$16={"CC025";"CC070";"CC100";"CC200";"CSM015";"CSM025";"CSM065";"CSM125";"CSM195"})*($C$11-C22))

But upper gives still wrong results, will check again.

Comment: Look, I tried on this way: =SUMPRODUCT(($B$16={"CC025";"CC070";"CC100";"CC200";"CSM015";"CSM025";"CSM065";"CSM125";"CSM195"})*(3,14*($C$8:$K$8^2)/4*SUM(C19:C21)/1000))

And getting same results as your formula...but they are wrong.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know which positions to multiply, maybe you understand the problem and know how to customize the formula properly!

Comment: Will write it soon, gimme a sec

Comment: The formula I originally gave is probably for cell 21, doesn't it work? If so I will review

Comment: let see my image. formula result `2.26 ~ 2.3` Perhaps you have rounded it up

Comment: Yea...rounded! That is fine now! Why drop down is not referencing properly, got idea?

Comment: my formula not work with dropdown? if so, let's check space `" "`in dropdown. or just type `=B16="CC025"` to check equal.

Comment: For CC025 is TRUE only but others FALSE.  Strange, let me see wth is this all of a sudden.

Comment: go to data-> datavalidation -> see list address then go to this address -> edit. or more simply, recreate a new column area and add new datavalidatation to B16

Comment: You may have typed O -> 0 . haha

Comment: Haha..no no! That was already checked :D  But still man, I cant get results using this row referemce: *$C$8:K8^2)   simply getting nonsense of results. I assume it is because of that.  If I remove "K8" from array then works only for one Type on drop down. 

Ah I checked boolean again, it works - didnt change properly b16 = "CC070" and so on.

Comment: maybe I know why it doesn't work: because of the accent format ` ; ` and ` , ` mine and you are different. let's change ` ; ` or ` , ` in  array {...} [ example `{"CC025","CC070",..}` or `{"CC025";"CC070";..}` ]

Comment: I came to the problem!! You were partly right!! BUT!  This was an issue: =3,14*SUMPRODUCT(($B$16={"CC025"\"CC070"\"CC100"\"CC200"\"CSM015"\"CSM025"\"CSM065"\"CSM125"\"CSM195"})*$C$8:$K$8^2)/4*SUM(C18:C20)/1000

So "backslash" if thats name :D "\"  damn it.

Comment: In Germany seems it is so :D      but now I got an issue in second formula with an array partt. $C$11-C21   this also has to go all over like previous with all drop downs. But using this: 
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$16={"CC025"\"CC070"\"CC100"\"CC200"\"CSM015"\"CSM025"\"CSM065"\"CSM125"\"CSM195"})*($C$11-C21))

I got only got one value in drop down.

Comment: Ah got it!! =SUMPRODUCT(($B$16={"CC025"\"CC070"\"CC100"\"CC200"\"CSM015"\"CSM025"\"CSM065"\"CSM125"\"CSM195"})*($C$11:$K$11-H21))

Works perfectly!! All of it :D

Comment: I marked your answer as an ANSWER =)  thanks a lot man! this was great, and a bit new things to learn!! Here are colors :
-orange, accent 6, light 80%
-white background1, darker 5%
-light yellow and dark blue, text2, light 40% :D